# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'

Tags: django, server

i wanted to run my project in server. Well when I start the server I get an error *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named*`django_heroku`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wl56.png)

but i don't use heroku

thanks for answer

Comment: Why does your `settings.py` do `import django_heroku` then?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the import statement of django_heroku library in the project settings. If you don't use it just comment it and run. It will fix this issue.